# Error: "Log File not found! " when running .bib file

Tags: bibtex, logging

I'm using TextMaker. This is my first time using `bibtex`. I tried a simple example found in forums where I created a `.bib` file and ofcourse a `.tex` file. Problem occurred when I tried to run my `bib` file. It says "Log File not found!". My `.tex` file runs fine.

I know this is not supposed to be that complicated. As I just want to create a simple bibliography using `bibtex`.

Comment: Are you running your `.bib` through (La)TeX or BiBTeX?

Comment: You shouldn't have to run your `.bib` file through either LaTeX or BibTeX. Assuming your main `.tex` file is called `ljl.tex`, say, all you need to do (assuming no bugs that crash the compilation) is to run LaTeX on `ljl.tex`, then BibTeX on the same file, then LaTeX twice more.

Comment: @Mico BibTeX must be run on the `.aux` file (the same file could be understood as on `ljl.tex`. It is true that you don't need the extensions. So one can run `latex ljl`, and then `bibtex ljl`.

Comment: @Guido: Thanks for clarifying the matter. Upon rereading what I wrote, I agree it's not as clear as it should be. :-)